# Subtract sum of two columns of two unrelated tables in mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two unrelated tables with an amount column. I want to to sum the amount from the two columns and subtract the two sums, all this is done in an API I am working on.

```
  case 'amountleft':
  
 $warehouse = $_POST['warehouse'];
 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(price) AS amount FROM purchases WHERE warehouse = ?");
 $stmttwo = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(amountrequested) AS amounttwo FROM fundruequest WHERE warehouse = ?");
 
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$warehouse);
 $stmttwo->bind_param("s",$warehouse);
 
 $stmt->execute();
  $stmttwo->execute();
 
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmttwo->store_result();
 
 if($stmt->num_rows > 0 && $stmttwo->num_rows > 0){
 

 $stmt->bind_result($amount);
 $stmttwo->bind_result($amounttwo);
 $stmt->fetch();
 $stmttwo->fetch();

 $newamount = $stmttwo - $stmt;
 
 $newamount = array(
 'newamount'=>$newamount
 );
 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'Amount Allocated Gotten'; 
 $response['newamount'] = $newamount; 
 }else{
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'Amount Allocated Not GOtten';
 }
 
 
 break;
```

The Table structure

```
purchases table.
ID               Price
1                 2
2                 34
4                 12
5                 87

fundruequest Table.
ID               amountrequested
1                 89
2                 67
4                 32
5                 56
```

I want to sum amount requested and subtract it from the sum of price in purchases table.

the query does not work.

Comment: you can try fetching the values from database and managing the subtraction/addition in php

Comment: how please, I tried that but it did not work

Comment: See UNION (and perhaps `*-1`)

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: @AnkitJindal I tried what you said, I have edited the question to reflect that but it is still not working, it looks like a  simpler approach than writing an SQL query that does the sum and subtracts it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS amount
  FROM 
(
SELECT price, warehouse FROM purchases
UNION ALL
SELECT price * -1, warehouse FROM sales
) x
WHERE warehouse = ?;
```

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)